# Creating a virtual wallet to display balance in a store

Tags: wallet, client

I have a store that uses bitcoin as a payement. 
I want to make users deposit to their balance in the site, as I saw in many sites, 
a bitcoin address is generated for each user to deposit funds to it, and use his dashboard in the site to withdaw it to his BTC address anytime.
I am using PHP. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a way much better practice to generate a new address for every new order and not per user, as this would imply [address reuse](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address_reuse) for returning customers, [which is generally discouraged](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address_reuse#Problems). Then the users won't have to keep their funds on your website and will only pay the exact amount for each order.

You can take a look at [these open source projects for bitcoin written in PHP](https://github.com/search?l=PHP&q=bitcoin&type=Repositories) for starters.

Comment: i accepted your answer. But can you explain more how do i add balance in the site automatically when funds are recieved?

Comment: The wallet keeps the balance for you. You will be notified for every each new payment as soon as it takes place. Allow for a few blocks to get confirmed, then you can dispatch the bought items from your store.

Comment: The link you gave me has many libraries that are useless, which library you're talking about?

Comment: None in particular. You can create a new question and ask the members who are into PHP to suggest the best for your case.